# Using numpy functions when dtype is object

Tags: python, numpy

I have a a column in my numpy array which has a bunch of `long`s and a few `NaN`s. There are no other `float`s in it. If I convert the entire column to `float` I will lose precision.

If I don't convert the entire column to `float`, I cannot use numpy functions like `isnan` or `isfinite` because the array is of type object despite the elements being valid types.

Is there anyway of preserving precision while being able to use numpy functions?

```
a = np.array([10**50,19**50,float('NaN')])

a
#outputs:
array([100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000L,
   8663234049605954426644038200675212212900743262211018069459689001L,
   nan], dtype=object)

np.isnan(a)

#outputs error:

ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely 
coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: You could also consider using a masked array instead of using `NaN`'s.  That may or may not fit your problem, but it avoids the need to directly call `np.isnan`, etc.

Comment: @JoeKington actually I need np.isnan to mask my arrays...I don't actually know where the Nans are...I will accept Zhangxaochen's answer as it does what I need currently...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [1760]: np.isnan(a.astype(float))
Out[1760]: array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

So if precision is not that important, just `a=a.astype(float)`.

Comment: I like this solution. I will need to use other numpy functions but for this situation is a good work around.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility could just ignoring the `nan`s:

```
ii = np.where([type(a) is long for a in A if type(a)]
B = 5*A[ii]
```